# twig: How to get request string?

Tags: php, twig

I have a url: http://myserver.com/mypage?vid=1234

I want to output 1234 on to the page. I have tried this but it is not working:

```
{{ app.request.get('vid') }}
```

what am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Twig is a templating engine. It has no knowledge of requests and such. It only knows how to display things you give it. Look at the documentation.

Comment: Sorry I am not a php developer.  What is this syntax then: app.request.get('vid')

Comment: Most likely the `vid` value is removed before twig looks for it

Comment: Are you just trying to pass a parameter into your twig file? If so, why not do that in your controller? Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? There might be an easier way.

Comment: I found out that the site was using Craft CMS. I ended up using the Craft lib to get the request query string.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using the "query" object :

```
{{ app.request.query.get('vid') }}
```

But you should get this value in the controller and then pass it to twig.

EDIT : This answer is based on the asumption that you are using Symfony Framework

Comment: This won't work because `{{ app.request.get('vid') }}` already looks for `vid` in query object in the first place

Comment: It is not working. I tried {{ app.request.query.get('vid') }} and it shows blank

Comment: You're right, I forgot app.request is the Symfony request object. You should try getting the get input from the controller

Comment: ok. I don't work with symphony much. Is symphony a php framework? I'll look it up after this comment:0 ) I'll google it.